# Is it secure to use the same key for encrypting multiple fields with AES 256 symmetric encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I have an AES256 key that I use for encrypting SSNs in my application.  Now I need to encrypt the security answer.

Is it advisable to use different keys to encrypt each field or can I use the same key to encrypt multiple fields?

Comment: belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

We have one key for most encrypted fields and another for a few extra sensitive fields.  The thought behind it is if someone gets the common key, they still would not have access to the most sensitive information.

I have no idea how this fits in "best practices", but it has worked well for us so far.

Regardless of what you do, someone determined to hack it will find a way.  You just need to find the balance and level required for the type of information you are storing.  When it comes to SSN and other personal information like that, it is hard to be "overly secure".

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep to best practices it is possible to use the same key for encrypting multiple fields. With best practices I mean that you need to use a random IV if you are using AES CBC encryption.

Note that the key size of AES is not that important. Having a good key infrastructure, good server security and a cryptographically secure protocol is much more important. AES-128 or even triple DES is almost infinitely safer than AES-256 if the latter is deployed improperly.